# Magic of Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am using jdk 1.6 
My main method :

```
exmp3<String , Integer> exmp3 = new exmp3( "ravi" , new ArrayList<String>());
                exmp3.put(5);
                exmp3.put(15);
                exmp3.put(20);
                ArrayList<Integer> a =  exmp3.getObject();
                System.out.println(a.size());
```

class exmp3 :

```
public class exmp3<ABC , XYZ>
{
    private ABC abc ;
    private ArrayList<XYZ> xyz;

        public exmp3(ABC abc , ArrayList<XYZ> xyz)
        {
            this.xyz =  xyz;
        }

        public void put(int i)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> a =  (ArrayList<Integer>) this.xyz;
            a.add(i);
        }

        public ArrayList<XYZ> getObject()
        {
            return xyz;
        }
    }
```

My query is while creating instance of `exmp3` in `main` method why `String` is accepted as parametric type of `ArrayList` where as i have mentioned `exmp3<String , Integer> exmp3` in `main` method.

Comment: Class names should start with an uppercase letter :)

Comment: try the diamond operator (in java 7) new exmp3<>

Comment: your class declaration is weird, when using generics you should first think of what you expect and what are the limitations of each of your generic variables/methods. check this version :http://pastebin.com/0tD37myU

Comment: @TecHunter :  i agree with your opinion , i was just trying to learn by the method of trial and error. I would never use such kind of code practically.

Comment: @RaviJain oh ok, good luck then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using this :

```
new exmp3( "ravi" , new ArrayList<String>());
```

which is almost the same as

```
new exmp3<Object,Object>( "ravi" , new ArrayList<String>());
```

Arguments in methods or constructors never defines the types when instancing. the compiler only sees (if you don't think about erasure) :

```
new exmp3( String , ArrayList);
```

while your instance is declared to use this definition :

```
public class exmp3<Object, Object>
{
    private Object abc ;
    private ArrayList<Object> xyz;

        public exmp3(Object abc , ArrayList<Object> xyz)
        {
            this.xyz =  xyz;
        }

        public void put(int i)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> a =  (ArrayList<Integer>) this.xyz;
            a.add(i);
        }

        public ArrayList<Object> getObject()
        {
            return xyz;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not specifying the type arguments for the constructor call. Either explicitly specify them (`new exmp3<String, Integer>(...)`) or have the compiler figure them out (`new exmp3<>(...)`, requires JDK7+).

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using a raw type. `new exmp3(..)` means that any type information is disregarded. Change this to: `new Exmp3<String, Integer>` (Java 5-6) or `new Exmp3<>` (Java 7)

The compiler normally shows you a warning in this case that you should not use raw types. In short - when using raw types it works as Java pre-1.5 - i.e. no generics.

Comment: can you please explain it more or provide a helpful resource.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation. And here's the resources http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html